# How to insert spacing for start of paragraph?

Tags: spacing

How would I add some spacings starting at the black arrows in the picture below? As in, I am trying to move the text towards the right a bit, like starting a new paragraph. Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example} % same for example numbers
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}


\title{My Thesis Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{\today}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\roman{enumi}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Addition}

\begin{exmp}
This is just an example. This is just an example.This is just an example.
\\
\\    \textit{This is just an example.}
\\
\\    \textit{This is just an example.This is just an example.This is just an example.This is just an example.}
\\
\\    \textit{This is just an example.This is just an example.gsdasdasdasdasfdasfaxbcxbcxb}
\\
\\    \textit{Prove that for $4 < x < 122$,
\begin{equation}
x^2 + 5x = 235325y \nonumber
\end{equation}
is the solution to $n^2$.}
\end{exmp}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit] The problem is that you use `\\\\` to start a new paragraph. Just use an empty line. (Thanks David) [/Edit]

You probably want to use

```
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
```

or a more convenient length. Though `1em` is quite common.

Comment: also you should _always_ start a paragraph with a blank line not with `\\\\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle whoops, I hadn't checked his code example well enough. Only if there was no `\usepackage{parskip}`.